# Syncing PHP Git project's MySQL structure

Tags: php, mysql, git, ubuntu, wampserver

I've recently learned to use git, have a nice editor that supports it, and a nice hook that uploads everything to a live site upon push. So now I have a local version, a dev testing version and a live version, and everything is grand. The only problem which I haven't managed to find is a nice solution on how to efficiently sync the MySQL structure between the databases.

The 2 scenarios I often face on extending my projects are either add extra columns or create new tables. I often do this through phpmyadmin, and although I can copy paste the given change as SQL, I strive for a more efficient solution than having to copy paste in 3+ repositories.

Currently these are my methods I consider, but I'd prefer a more efficient one.

**Repositories:**

- live - live site on server
- dev - dev site on server
- local - local site on computer

## Method #1

Copy/paste all SQL commands generated by phpmyadmin into every project's database.

- Not really an efficient solution in the end

## Method #2

Somehow (do inspire me) fill a php file with an array full of all generated SQL commands from phpmyadmin, then execute that php file from a hook. I'd do all of my structure changes in one of the server's repositories, and upon pull from local and merge to live, change the MySQL structure.

- Would be neat, but not fully sure how to execute it
- Needs to work on both ubuntu server and local wampserver

## Method #3

Some nice solution through MySQL that works both on server and locally.

- No idea how that would work.

Thanks for your time, and if you know some better method do share! I'm looking for an automatic solution that makes sence.

Comment: I assume its only the structure you wish to update?

Comment: http://davedevelopment.co.uk/2008/04/14/how-to-simple-database-migrations-with-phing-and-dbdeploy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that both CodeIgniter which I use both seem to have nice methods to handle this. Didn't know to search with the word [**Migration**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/migration.html).

Hopefully all who finds this question notes this; the keyword is **Database Migration** to find good solutions.

Thanks to the comments for pointing where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.liquibase.org/

Also I saw at yii nice migrations: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration

If CodeIgniter support something like this -- it's also good. Yes -- I see it's support: both up and down.

If man, that will work with migrations knows programming languages -- then it's ok to use tools from frameworks. If not -- then it's better to use xml/config like things like http://www.liquibase.org/

Comment: Definatly worth considering on other projects. Thanks!